# Respected argument for max() function in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def find_smallest_circle_sqtime(list):
    inv_number_of_elements = 1.0 / len(list);
    smallest_circle = MyCircle(inv_number_of_elements * sum(p.get_x() for p in list),
                               inv_number_of_elements * sum(p.get_y() for p in list), .1);

    smallest_circle.radius = max(smallest_circle.centre.sub(p).norm() for p in list);
    return smallest_circle
```

Where I'm getting the radius of the farthest point in `list` relative to the `smallest_circle.centre`. But actually I need to get the point itself. How can I do that in the most pythonic way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function allows you to provide a custom ordering function (via the `key` argument):

```
max(list, key=lambda p: smallest_circle.centre.sub(p).norm())
```

And please don't use semicolons. And you shouldn't use names of built-in types/functions as variable names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked. I'm still new to python and semicolons are kind of habbit. Do they make any harm to a program?

Comment: You're right about built-in name, of course. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewLavq no, they're just superfluous.